# Python: how to split lists of different sizes in an object variable with string values separated by commas?

Tags: python, data-analysis

i'm a beginner in python and data analytics, and i have the below issue that i cannot resolve!

lets say i have the following variable of type object having the following:

```
0                                             [Julian Sims]
1                                          [Bernard Gillis]
2         [Damien Bell, Desmen Noble, Herman Seagers, La...
3         [Stacie Philbrook, Christopher Ratliffe, Antho...
4         [Danielle Imani Jameison, Maurice Eugene Edmon...
5         [Rebeika Powell, Kayetie Melchor, Misty Nunley...
6         [Greg Griego, Sara Griego, Zephania Griego, Ja...
7                                                        []
8                                                        []
9                                           [Deshaun Jones]
10                                        [Demetrius Davis]
...
...
...
```

there is more than 200,000 rows and they are of different sizes.

what i want to do is to see if any name is repeated; show where is it repeated, and show all other names that are in the same row.

I tried to store each name in a row in a new variable to do group by later and see if any is repeated, but i'm not sure how!

i tried below code but result was not what i wanted

```
names = []
row = str(name_list).split(",")
for x in row :
    names.append(x)
```

but i got the following:

```
['0                                             [Julian Sims]\n1                                          [Bernard Gillis]\n2         [Damien Bell',
 ' Desmen Noble',
 ' Herman Seagers',
 ' La...\n3         [Stacie Philbrook',
 ' Christopher Ratliffe',
 ' Antho...\n4         [Danielle Imani Jameison',
 ' Maurice Eugene Edmon...\n5         [Rebeika Powell',
 ' Kayetie Melchor',
 ' Misty Nunley...\n6         [Greg Griego',
 ' Sara Griego',
 ' Zephania Griego',
 ' Ja...\n7                                                        []\n8                                                        []\n9                                           [Deshaun Jones]\n10                                        [Demetrius Davis]
```

i'm trying to create a graph chart to show who are connected to each other if any is repeated

please let me know if there is a better way to do things.

much appreciated

Comment: Please provide an example of expected output.

Comment: You are converting the row to a string, which converts '[', ']', and newlines. Use the join method to join the elements of a list by the character/s of your choice. `",".join( row )` But as Jab said, please provide expected output

Comment: so what is the exact help you need here? how to extract each line for you to further split with comma? or even how to solve the whole problem of finding duplicate?

Comment: hi guys, thanks for your help, i have responded with a comment in the first solution, let me know if there is more clarifications needed!

Answer (score 0):

---

Assuming that `name_list` is the whole text, I would use

```py
lines = [line[line.find('[')+1:line.find(']')].split(',') for line in name_list]
```

to get the names in each line as a list of lists. This finds the opening bracket, then slices the string from that bracket to the closing bracket and splits the content by commas.
To access the names in line four (indexed from zero, as in name_list),

```py
>>>lines[4]
['Danielle Imani Jameison', 'Maurice Eugene Edmon...']
```

I'm not sure I understand where you're trying to go from there, but if you explain a little more I'll be glad to help.

EDIT:

```py
name_list = '''0                                             [Julian Sims]
1                                          [Bernard Gillis]
2         [Damien Bell, Desmen Noble, Herman Seagers, La...]
3         [Stacie Philbrook, Christopher Ratliffe, Antho...]
4         [Danielle Imani Jameison, Maurice Eugene Edmon...]
5         [Rebeika Powell, Kayetie Melchor, Misty Nunley...]
6         [Greg Griego, Sara Griego, Zephania Griego, Ja...]
7                                                        []
8                                              [Sara Griego]
9                                           [Deshaun Jones]
10                                        [Demetrius Davis]'''.split('\n')
lines = [[name.strip() for name in line[line.find('[')+1:line.find(']')].split(',')] for line in name_list]
names = [name.strip() for line in lines for name in line if name]
seen = set()
dups = set(name for name in names if name in seen or seen.add(name))

if len(dups) == 0: print("No duplicates.")

info = {name:[] for name in dups}
for i in range(len(lines)):
    for name in dups:
        if name in lines[i]: info[name].append(i)
print(info)
```

I've slightly modified the sample of data you provided to include a duplicate and have end brackets for each line (as I assume the real data does). This code prints an object containing any duplicate names, and the lines they appear on. The result with the sample data is `{'Sara Griego': [6, 8]}`, which seems to be what you're looking for? If you'd rather have the two lists of names instead of the two line numbers, you can change the outer `for` loop to:

```py
for line in lines:
    for name in dups:
       if name in line: info[name].append(line)
```

Please let me know if anything in here doesn't match what you were thinking of.

Comment: Hi Shawn, i'm working with gun crimes data as my topic for my Capstone project for school. i'm trying to apply any machine learning model, but i couldn't figure out which one based on the nature of my data. Graph model was an idea to see if there are people involved in multiple gun incidents, and show all other names with that one. i'm not sure if there is any duplicates as they could either be in prison or dead. so before trying anything, i wanted to make sure there is duplicates first. so i wanted to create a list that has one name in each row, then do a value_counts, ....CONT

Comment: if there is no name repeated; there is no point for me to try to figure out graph model on this data set. the resources i found online do not help me with this data set, but i still believe i could do it. i really appreciate your help :)

Comment: I've updated the answer with what I hope is the code you're looking for. Good luck with the project!

Comment: Thanks Shawn! this is exactly the output i'm looking for.

i tried modifying the code like:
name_list = Full_list.split('\n')

i'm getting this error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

Full_list has the over 200000 records i should work with

Comment: Oh, I assumed you were reading from a text file with python’s `open()` function. It sounds like you’re using pandas instead? I haven’t used pandas personally, but it looks like `name_list = Full_list.to_list()` may work. If not, please post a sample of what that method returns.

Comment: yes i am using pandas. i tried this fix, on the next line i tried to split it with: ""name_list = name_list.split('\n')"" and this time i'm getting this error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'           now i'm not exactly sure what .split work on!!

Comment: The split method is for strings. I used it in my example just to split a large string into the equivalent of what you’d get using the native `open()` function, so you don’t need to worry about using it. If you try to run the code without the line you added, does it work? If not, could you post a sample of what name_list looks like?

Comment: i made a github repository for this, please find my code for this issue here: https://github.com/EBBOOO/Python     file name: finding name duplicates issue      data is from: https://www.kaggle.com/jameslko/gun-violence-data

Comment: please let me know if there is any more information needed! i really hope i get this done! i feel very close

Comment: The data requires an account to download, so I haven't tested this on my end, but I think it should work if you change the first line of `In[4]` from `name_list = participant_name.split('\n')` to `name_list = participant_name.tolist()`.